# Linux command for running Chef roles

Tags: chef-infra

I am running a Chef cookbook in local mode. Can someone tell me how to run the roles, please? What is the Linux command for running Chef roles?

Comment: Do you mean "solo" mode?

Comment: Not Solo. I'm running Chef Zero.

Comment: Use  `role[your_role_name]` instead of a recipe name in the runlist and it will be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is the same, the only difference is the run list you give to chef-client:

```
chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'role[name]'
```